# Blue screen upon login to ubuntu

Tags: 20.04

Im new to ubuntu and I installed 20.04

Its been fine the last 3 days.. but now when I boot my machine, icons are missing and its just blue background..

I wanted to do some diagnostics via terminal, but the terminal does not open. Any idea what causes this? And how can I reset this back to default or factory state?[image]

Comment: From the `grub` menu try booting in recovery mode. See: https://www.howtogeek.com/196740/how-to-fix-an-ubuntu-system-when-it-wont-boot/

Comment: Wow never seen that one. Do you have an Nvidia card.  Till you get that sorted out its hard to move on.

Comment: By the way, you may be able to open a terminal by typing <CTRL><ALT><T>.

Comment: You didn't make any changes to your default python3 in the last session where it worked normally did you?  or add extensions to your system?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem after upgrading to 20.04 from 16.04. As mentioned above in the comments using CRTL+ALT+T brings up the terminal. Use `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` command to install the dock (launcher) and `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons` to install the icons. You can add `--reinstall` in this command if it was already installed before. You will need to logoff and login again to get the dock and icons back.

For the blue screen, just right click and choose "Display Settings". Go to "Background" from the left pane to pick your favourite background.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me with following commands.

1. ctrl + alt + (F1 to F6) to start ttyl
2. sudo dpkg --configure -a
3. sudo apt update
4. sudo apt upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed by running the tty by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F3 and then ran the command

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to upgrade my machine to Ubuntu 22.04 to fix this

```bash
sudo do-release-upgrade
```